# Get objects from MongoDB document where an authenticated user is listed/associated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB that contains 2 documents - `User` and `Clinic`.

The User document contains the data related to the app users - ie. user accounts.

The Clinic document contains information related to a clinic, which includes a list of providers, where the providers are references to the `User` model.

The schema for these models are below.

**User.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
module.exports = User= mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

**Clinic.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ClinicSchema = new Schema({
  providers: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      }
    }
  ],
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
module.exports = Clinic = mongoose.model('clinics', ClinicSchema);
```

On the front end I have the users 'profile' where they view their information. To populate this view, I have a GET route on the backend that serves the user's data (note: they must be logged in to access).

Before the data is sent from the backend, I want to find what Clinics the user is a provider for (ie. clinic objects where they are in the `provider` array) and add this to the JSON response. Adding the data to the JSON res is easy, but I am struggling to workout how to look through the `Clinic` entries and return the clinic objects where `req.user.id is === provider.user.toString()`

**Current route**

```
router.get(
  '/profile',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    User
      .findById(req.user.id)
      .then(user => {
        Clinic
          .find()
          .then(clinics => {
            userClinic = clinics.filter(clinic => {
              clinic.providers.filter(provider => {
                provider.user.toString === req.user.id;
              });
            });
            console.log(userClinic);
          });
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json({notFound: 'User not found'}));
  }
);
```

In the code above, the `console.log(userClinic)` returns an empty array.

How can I get this route to `console.log(userClinic)` so that `userClinic` is an array of `Clinic` objects where the user is in the clinics `providers[]`?

Note: the console.log() will later be replaced with the logic to append the array to the object that gets returned as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say your `filter`s don't work properly, and there are several issues:

- your filtering functions don't `return` a value to be evaluated as truthy or falsy by `filter`: so, implicitly, these functions always `return undefined`, which is falsy, which leads to no element being validated by `filter` (i.e. empty array)
- you test `provider.user.toString === req.user.id;` whereas you probably meant `provider.user.toString() === req.user.id` (by the way, `provider.user` is certainly already a string)
- you don't really provide a filtering test (independently from the missing `return`) for the function used at `clinics.filter`, I suppose it would be something like `return clinic.providers.filter(...).length > 0` - alternatively you could use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which would be more adequate for this purpose

In the end, you'd have something like:

```
// don't forget to *declare* the variable with var/let/const!
let userClinics = clinics.filter(clinic => {
  return clinic.providers.find(provider => {
    return provider.user === req.user.id;
  });
});
```

However, this job could be done more easily. You could use MongoDB to sort the data for you instead of retrieving the whole collection. This should work:

```
route.get(... => {
  const promiseUser = User.findById(req.user.id);
  const promiseClinics = Clinic.find({
    "providers.user": req.user.id
  });
  Promise.all([promiseUser, promiseClinics]).then(results => {
    let user = results[0];
    let clinics = results[1];
    // do stuff with these profile data
  });
});
```